# Excel Named Function Parameters or UDF without Macros

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

It seems like a bit of an omission that there's no easy way to create a user-defined declarative function in Excel without defining a macro. I can't use XSLM with the uphill battle that will entail in the Enterprise, but I want to be able to define a function with intent thus.

**I want to do this;**

```
=BreakEven(C1:C20)
```

But I can't use a macro, although I can use a "named formula". The trouble is how to pass parameters to that? I've seen a couple of tricks (kludgy workarounds) but not for xslx.

I'd like to be able to define a Breakeven() function in another tab and reference it here passing in MORE THAN one parameter, two ranges in fact. I'm sure there's some way using string parsing but I can't see it.

I don't mind if the function doesn't look exactly like that, as long as it evaluates within the cell and I can parse it for 'intent'. For instance, this example (http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/ExcelNames09.asp) which I was unable to get to work in xlsx uses this syntax;

```
=IF(ROW(D3),CellColor)
```

Where "cellcolor" is the name of the function and D3 is the range parameter. The other solution I'm toying with is to define a function in column format with a variable argument list (this is two rows of an excel spreadsheet);

```
[Value][function][parameter1][parameter2][parameter3]
 24050  BreakEven C1:C20      A1:A20
```

It's not pretty, but the benefit of the latter is that it describes the function to an external reader. We *know* it's a breakeven function, whereas if we put the *actual* formula "OFFSET,INDIRECT,SUM()()()()etc" it would not be readable/parseable. Of course, in that case, I'd have to construct the value field by parsing the cells to the right in Excel, which would make the Value formula messy but at least it would be a self-describing row.

Can anyone suggest a better method?

Comment: IMHO there are no good solutions that avoid some kind of UDF. If you just want to avoid XLSM/XLSB you could put the function in an XLA addin, but presumably if you are forced to work in a VBA free environment that would also not be allowed. Other choices would be to use XLM (the original macro language which still works) or .NET automation addin or C++ XLL, but I suspect all these will face the same problem.

Comment: Hi Charles. Yes, we can't rely on users downloading and installing an addin from our site as we won't have a direct relationship with the Enterprise, so we have no idea what the policy might be. When you say XLM I'm guessing you mean to use with XLS, but either way, isn't XLM subject to the same macro restrictions? We could use XLSM and just have the user make the choice as to whether to run or not, but macros in general have a bad rep and they probably won't. It's infuriating that there's no way to create a non-macro, declarative UDF.

Comment: Well, yes there are some over-paranoid IT departments out there (AFAIK the most recent VBA virus seen in the wild was in 1996!), but if its just VBA thats the problem you can write your UDFs in pretty much whatever language takes your fancy, and/or you can easily build an installer that installs your workbook, doumentation and associated addin.

Comment: Well certainly the problem is one of perception, but if our customers download an XSLX from our website as a form to fill in for re-upload later, a macro dependency would be a nail in the coffin. The bar of entry is suddenly that much greater for adoption if there's a binary that needs to be installed first, and the macro warning probably won't be accepted from an Internet site, even if their corporate policy happens to allow them to download signed macros. There's no way to be sure of bypassing that warning altogether so a pure Excel solution is what's needed.

Comment: It frustrates me, because the main danger in VBA comes from things like new FileSystemObject(). They could easily have restricted UDFs to excel only functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Poor-man's UDF

So I think what we're going to have to do is this;

```
      A      B         C           D           E
1    [Value][function][parameter1][parameter2][parameter3]
2     24050  BreakEven     C1:C20      A1:A20
3       111      mySum          1          10         100
```

Where "BreakEven" is a "named function". Here's the formula for "mySum";

```
=sum(C1:E1)
```

To evaluate functions listed in B, we just put this in column A (transposing the same value for all rows in column A;

```
=value(B)
```

This works because A2 and A3 both evaluate column B as a value, which causes BreakEven and Sum to run (as poor-man's UDFs) in the context of A2 and A3. The range (C1:E1) is relative of course.

So in effect, we can write any function name in column B (as long as there's a corresponding named function defined in the workbook which can be as complex as you like). Columns C, D and E act as the parameters for the function on the same row.

I would have loved to just be able to write the following in column A instead;

```
=mySum(1,10,100)
```

But in the absence of that support, the mechanism above serves to provide a readable parameterised function that would be understandable by a user, that's also machine readable (works in CSV too) and allows us to offload our re-usable functions to a library sheet somewhere in the workbook for maintenance.

Not perfect, but an acceptable compromise, unless anyone has a clever way of doing this in a single cell?

Comment: no such thing as named functions, only named ranges - refferences to worksheet ranges and virtual ranges or named formulas if you like ;) and a range or a formula does not accept arguments - neither `=sum(A1)(B1)` nor `=A1(B1)` will work

Comment: Yep, it's a real omission if you ask me, that's why I've gone with this solution. It's not as easy to write but seems to work almost as well as a named function, since we can't do that.

Comment: i can't begin to imagine all the bugs that could possibly come out of it.. but a new feature "named functions" or an option to enable harmless UDF without renaming .xlsm would be real nice :)

Comment: I can't imagine too many bugs, if we're only talking about declarative functions, not algorithmic ones. Fully declarative functions, which are just named compilations of built-in excel functions should be fine. However, if those functions were allowed looping, or other such programmatic constructs then yes, I could see that being an issue.

Comment: @cirrus I think this is what I want but I'm having a hard time understanding it.  Pardon the fact that it's six years in the future but could you give step-by-step instructions for implementing `mySum`?

Comment: @AndrewKeeton three years in the future calling.  I think what he's doing here is defining a function in the name manager and passing a range as an argument to it, and then in the named range referencing the actual data range.  For an extremely simple example, use name manager to assign `A1` to `args`.  Then define a function `test` as `=sum(indirect(args))`.  Put some data in another column and put the string reference to that data in A1.  Image attached.  https://imgur.com/SOVnKoO

Comment: But it should not be long before LAMDA is released.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but easier to illustrate here than in a comment. Although you can't rename formulas in a simplistic way - I like your suggestion actually I've never thought about that before; but then I've never worked in a non-macro environment so this has never occurred-  you can add notes into the actual formula explaining what it does. For example:

```
=N("This is a really complex BreakEven Formula")+SUM(3,4,5)
```

Is a perfectly valid formula. As I said, not really an answer, but could potentially add clarity to a complex formula

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a small trick

For example to create effectively a cuberoot UDF that emulates =cuberoot(x) then name a variable as cuberoot with a 'value' like this.

=(RC[-1])^(1/3)

Now you can either do this using a temporary switch to RC mode, or put the cursor in say cell E5 and type the name value as =(D5)^(1/3)

Now whenever you need a cuberoot you can put the argument in any cell and put =cuberoot in the cell to its right. It really works and follows true Excel rules.

I use it for multiparameter models that have the single 'argument' Time as a dependent variable. I then define the term Model as the model equation eg =a+b*Time+c*Time^2

where a,b,c are already named locations holding unique parameter values -

and then define Time as =RC[-1]

My sheets are filled with cells simply saying =Model  and have the required time value to the left (ie their argument). It is simple to extend to multi arg functions using multiple cells. It usually fits in well with spreadsheet layouts. Change the definition of your model once in the define name box and all places change simultaneously.

I have a function called ToDMS which takes the decimal degree value in the preceding cell and converts it to a deg Min and Sec string - very tidy.
You need the degrees to be in a single cell but want it in the alt. form in another cell

elegant, simple  and it works

Bob Jordan